# Unable to create table in SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to test out some ideas in `SQL Fiddle`, but I am having a hard time even getting it to work.

When I copy and paste other peoples queries it seems to work fine, but when I do something as simple as changing the table name, it suddenly stalls and fails.

Here is some test code I am trying to run in the Schema area. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    PROD_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PROD_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PROD_COST VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(PROD_ID)
);
```

Comment: SQLfiddle is broken for sometimes now... Try it locally.

Comment: Try [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler) instead

Comment: This code works fine for me, maybe try a different browser? OR maybe try clearing your browser cache and trying again?

Comment: I tried in Chrome at first, then Firefox. At that time, it still wasn't working.

I just tried it on Firefox again and it seems to be working :-P I guess I'll be using Firefox for this!

Thanks! I'll mark JeffUK's answer as soon as I can

Comment: Its works fine at my end. Here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/580cef/6)

Comment: Probably best to just delete the question, it's not going to help anyone in the future!